# Localhost 8080 is not allowed 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: web-services, ionic-framework, ionic2, cross-domain, aem

Building the app and running on the iPhone device gives the following errors:

[image]

I managed to get the details of the request sent from iOS Device, please check the below image is the request is valid or we need to do change something related to sending requests because there is no other place we can make any changes except the way we are sending requests

Header sending in the request is showing here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To enable cross-origin requests, the *server* that is responding to the request needs to set headers that will tell the requesting browser (which is on a different domain) that it is allowed to load the resource from the different domain.  Essentially, on the server (localhost) you will need add the headers to essentially white-list the calling domain as one that is allowed to fetch resources cross domain.

This is a useful article to help you ramp: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Also see http://excellencenodejsblog.com/handing-cors-for-your-mobile-app/